# http request haproxy cut string

Tags: apache, http, if-statement, xmlhttprequest, haproxy

I have a question about a http request in haproxy. I have the following problem.

i have a variable url e.g.

```
http://mywebsite.com/job/1/hello-world/display/redirect
```

Everything between `http://mywebsite.com/` and

```
/display/redirect
```

can be variable. Now I want everything that goes to .`..../display/redirect` to be cut off so that goes to `http://mywebsite.com/job/1/hello-world` without /display/redirect there is a way to define that ? I have the possibility to define fixed urls but how is that with variable urls where only the end is always according to the principle ?

I've been thinking about something like :

```
http-request redirect code 301 location http://mywebsite.com/ [..] if {path_beg [..]/display/redirect}
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked about paths *ending* with a pattern, so you wouldn't use `path_beg` (path begins with) -- you'd use `path_end` (path ends with) for the match.

Then use the `path` fetch and the `regsub()` converter to rewrite the path with the pattern removed.  Using `regsub()` requires HAProxy 1.6 or later.

```
http-request redirect code 301 location %[path,regsub(/display/redirect$,)] if { path_end /display/redirect }
```